# Rails 3: Json problem on the client side

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3

I've the code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reports = <%= @reports.to_json %>;
</script>
```

and in the output I've a result with `"` replaced by `&quot;`

```
"[{\"status\":\"available\",
...
...
...
```

how to say rails to provide raw json data so javascript can understand it? By the way `<%= raw @reports.to_json %>` doesn't seems to work.

Sultan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
var reports = <%= @reports.to_json.html_safe %>;
```

You may also want to read up on [Safebuffers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html) on [Katz's blog](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) (Rails core team member) or [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3).

Comment: I added some links so, if you wish, you can learn more about `html_safe` and the new XSS protection in Rails 3.

Comment: made my day :D oh, the internet!